# Google Play Services - No Internet Connection

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to get a leader board up and running using Google Play Services for android. I'm able to sign in and out without any issues. Additionally when I try and show the leader board it loads up and says " No internet connection ". My internet connection is clearing working and I can use the leader board in other applications on my phone ( not my apps ). Has anyone encountered this problem before?

I've also been seeing this error in LogCat however I've read that I should just ignore it. The fact that I can sign in and out without any problems suggests this is a red herring. "The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included."

LogCat:

`02-27 13:55:09.196: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25477): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
02-27 13:55:09.246: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25477): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
02-27 13:55:09.261: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25477): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
02-27 13:55:11.106: W/PicturePileLayerContent(25477): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
02-27 13:55:11.106: W/PicturePileLayerContent(25477): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
02-27 13:55:12.126: W/PicturePileLayerContent(25477): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
02-27 13:55:12.351: W/GLSUser(14068): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
02-27 13:55:12.586: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(14103): untagSocket(153) failed with errno -22
02-27 13:55:12.586: E/Volley(14103): [25958] sm.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards/2131099679/scores?score=1&language=en_GB
02-27 13:55:12.596: W/LeaderboardAgent(14103): {"code":400,"errors":[{"message":"Invalid leaderboardId with value 2131099679.","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}`

Below is a screen shot from my device.

[image: no internet connection]

Comment: do you have internet persmission in menifest?

Comment: Can you post your logcat please as i have faced same error when my api console and game play service leaderboard didn't connect perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys. Yes, i have internet permissions added. After checking the LogCat data to post here I saw a warning for  the leader board. It appears its casting my string value to int where I've stored it in the xml.

Comment: Yup, sorry that was it, I have stupidly cast the int to a string rather than using getString(). Thanks for that though, it got me looking in the right place!

Comment: I had this problem many times when I was making an app. It just came and went. I never did anything. Some days it said no internet connection and some days it didnt. I get the feeling its a server side issue